# jQuery having trouble selecting things in different cases

Tags: jquery, encryption, codeigniter, jquery-selectors, base62

*Note: If you're 'just' a jQuery developer some things in this post may look a tad complex (Base62 encoding etc.) - it's really not. Although the more technical details are relevant to the question, the core is that jQuery won't select stuff with capitals. Thanks!*

Hi folks!

So I have a list generated by Ajax. When you click the list's title, it's ID is sent and the list item appears alongside it. Standard stuff.

Since we're using an auto_increment ID, we don't want the users knowing how many submissions there are in the database. So, I'm encoding it into Base62, then decoding back again. [Note that this is - or, *should* be, irrelevant to the problem].

So as my list is generated, this code is output. We're using CodeIgniter PHP alongside the jQuery - this is in a loop of database results. `$this->basecrypt->encode()` is a simple CI library to convert an integer (the ID) to Base62:

```
$('#title-<?php echo $this->basecrypt->encode($row->codeid); ?>').click(function() {
        alert("clicked");
        [...]
```

And then, further down the page:

```
<div id="title-<?php echo $this->basecrypt->encode($row->codeid);?>" class="title">
```

As you can see, this is all generated in the same loop - and viewing the outputted source code shows, for example:

`$('#title-1T').click[...]` and then `<div id="title-1T" [...]`

So, jQuery shouldn't have any trouble, right? It was all working fine until we started Base62-ing the IDs. **I believe that jQuery can't/won't select our IDs when they contain capital letters**.

Now forgive me if I'm wrong - I am, relatively speaking, fairly new to jQuery - but to test my point I changed my `$this->basecrypt->encode()` into Base36.
Before, it was using `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`
After, it was using `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

**With no capital letters, jQuery could select (and show the alert for testing purposes) just fine.**

So what can I do? Is it safe for me to continue just using numbers and lowcase letters, in Base36 - and if so, what's the maximum integer size this can go up to? If not, what can I do about jQuery's problematic selection process?

Thanks!

Jack

**EDIT:** Included below is some example code from the page.

This is a part of the script returned in the file ajaxlist.php - it's called from Ajax and appears a couple of seconds after the page loads. I added in `alert("clicked");` right near the beginning to see if that would appear - sadly, it doesn't...
    
    $(document).ready(function() {

```
    $('#title-<?php echo $this->basecrypt->encode($row->codeid); ?>').click(function() {
        alert("clicked");
        var form_data = {
            id: <?php echo $this->basecrypt->encode($row->codeid); ?>
        };

        $('.resultselected').removeClass('resultselected');
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('resultselected');

        $('#col3').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('code/viewajax');?>",
                type: 'POST',
                data: form_data,
                success: function(msg) {
                    $('#col3').html(msg);
                    $('#col3').fadeIn('fast');
                }
        });
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Also returned from the same file, at the same time as the code above (just beneath it) is this:

```
<div class="result">

    <div class="resulttext">

        <div id="title-<?php echo $this->basecrypt->encode($row->codeid);?>" class="title">
            <?php echo anchor('#',$row->codetitle); ?>
        </div>   [.......]
```

If this helps anymore, let me know!

---

**EDIT 2:** ACTUAL OUTPUT RETURNED TO THE BROWSER.

This was taken from Firebug, and is the returned data (Ajax) to the browser:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#title-1T').click(function() {
            alert("clicked");

            var form_data = {
                id: 1T      };

            $('.resultselected').removeClass('resultselected');
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass('resultselected');

            $('#col3').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:8888/code/viewajax",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: form_data,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        $('#col3').html(msg);
                        $('#col3').fadeIn('fast');
                    }
            });
            });
        }); 
    }); 
    </script>

    <div class="result">

        <div class="resulttext">

<div id="title-1T" class="title">

                <a href="http://localhost:8888/#"><p>This is an example </p></a>        </div>`

            <div class="summary">
                gibberish summary text      </div>

            <div class="bottom">


                <div class="author">
                    by <a href="http://localhost:8888/user/7/author">author</a>         </div>

                <div class="tagbuttoncontainer">
                                        <div class="tagbutton listv">
                                                    <span>tag1</span>
                        </div>  
                                </div>

                <!-- Now insert the rating system -->
                <div class="ratingswrapper">

                    <p>4.0</p> 
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Come on - you cannot say that shouldn't work... can you?!

Comment: The alpha case issue is definitely not your problem. jQuery has no issues with that, as a trivially simple test page can demonstrate. You should do a "view source" on one of your pages and inspect the identifier values.

Comment: Since it doesn't answer your question I'll post this here. If you really want to hide your id's and you can't access another item in the database, it might be worthwhile using a hashing algorithm instead, as base64 can easily be decoded. (Obviously adding a pepper into the hash).

Comment: Thanks Pointy. I've checked - they're definitely the same... And William, it's not that I 'seriously' want the users not to see the ID, I realise Base62 is decryptable. It just makes our URL segments look a bit nicer and slightly less obvious :)

Comment: What are the same?  I absolutely guarantee you that mixes of upper- and lower-case letters do not confuse jQuery.

Comment: Are you using the same "id" value for more than one element on the page?  It would probably help a lot if you would post some of the generated HTML here.

Comment: A test page demonstrating that jQuery understands capital letters: http://gutfullofbeer.net/hello.html

Comment: OK everybody, I'll admit it then - jQuery understands capitals... *facepalm*... By 'both the same' @Pointy, I mean both the selector and the <div> IDs are the same. And it's not very easy for me to show you the generated HTML, as the list is returned via Ajax so not viewable in View-Source... but I'll see what I can find with Firebug.

Comment: Update: wondering whether it was because of the Ajax-ey-ness, I tried running it on live('click', function() - still no luck, sorry...

Comment: Are you sure the php echo isn't adding unwanted spaces?

Comment: OK, I've pasted in some more 'full' examples, if that'll help! :) And fudgey, apparently it's not, the source shows everything output as would be expected.

Comment: Hmmm, try adding a `console.debug($('#title-<?php echo $this->basecrypt->encode($row->codeid); ?>'));` and see if it is giving you a valid target.

Comment: Hey, we've made a development! Well, two in fact.

So fudgey, I tried adding your console line in a perfectly valid, logical place. NOTHING HAPPENED?! So then, I commented out EVERYTHING from start to finish, leaving only the $(document).ready(function() { opening and the }); closing. Then I put your console line in between - and voila. It worked. So, it's like something in the code I've got stops everything from being executed...? The output of the Console said [div#title-1T.title], [div#title-1S.title], [div#title-1R.title], [div#title-1Q.title]...

Comment: Just done a few more attempts...

When basecrypt() is in Base36 it works fine! When it's in Base64 it fails...?!

Comment: BRAINWAVE! OK, so, the only real outputted differences between Base36 and Base64 is outputting in 64 outputs it as a letter/number combo - so, for example, 1N. With 36, my integers aren't high enough yet to output as a letter/number, so they come out as a number/number - e.g. 94 (or, #title-94...) - previously #title-[...] was a numerical ID which jQuery had no problem in selecting. Now that Base36 outputs a number, it still selects it fine. Only when a LETTER is added, does it fail to select it...! So where now?! :D

Comment: Would it be better to start a seperate question now as to why jQuery won't select it when it has a letter in?

Comment: Or am I still barking up the wrong tree...

Comment: OK! Added fully generated HTML.

Comment: @Jack - it's kinda funny now, but did you check the console logs for any error in the generated html? The moment I pasted this code on jsfiddle, it complained: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` and it was referring to `var form_data = { id: 1T };`. `1T` needs to be enclosed in quotes here. @fudgey posted an answer for this.

Comment: Reason why it started breaking when you introduced letters (caps or small) was because `{ id: 123 }` by itself is valid, but `{ id: A2 }` is not, as `A2` is not a valid literal of any type and has to be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Anurag, Fudgey too came up with the same idea and you are both undoubtedly correct. Thank you SO much to everybody who helped me, and thanks for putting up with me for so long, haha... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I found your problem... you need to put quotes around the variable in the form_data definition ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dV9Zx/)):

```
    var form_data = {
        id: "<?php echo $this->basecrypt->encode($row->codeid); ?>"
    };
```

I also had to add a `return false;` so the demo doesn't try to follow the link

Comment: :O - wow... thanks so much Fudgey! I mean, I guess looking back on it now it's a fairly simple one, but I would've never thought of that myself... just tried it on my source and it works perfectly. You, sir, are brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that jQuery is the problem.

Please double-check that the IDs you generate are unique to the page *and* conform to the [definition of ID tokens](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html):

> **`ID`** and **`NAME`** tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Also do a [validity test of your output HTML](http://validator.w3.org) to make sure your HTML is not broken in places where you did not look.

Comment: I'll go one better and say that I'm 100% positive that jQuery isn't the problem!

Comment: @Pointy: Yeah, I'm also sure it isn't. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: Well the ID definitely conforms, as they will always follow the structure "title-[something here]". The only Base62 characters will be 0-9, a-z, and A-Z, so it definitely complies.

Comment: @Jack: hm. I think revealing a simplified, but still non-working code sample might be necesary.

Comment: OK Tomalak, I've added some more to my original question :)

Comment: @Jack: Close, but no cigar. :) Better add a sample of the generated HTML, this is much easier to debug than the code that *generates* the HTML.

Comment: That IS the generated HTML! Or, do you mean $this->basecrypt?

Comment: Oh, wait, I see what you mean now... Well, the generated HTML is prettymuch exactly the same, except the PHP echoes are replaced with something Base62-ed like '1T' or '3S' or something. It always matches up with the jQuery selector, mind you.

Answer (score 1):

Why does

```
<div id="title" id="1T" [...]
```

contain two ids?

Comment: Sorry! That was an honest mistake, just a typo. I've fixed up the question.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't solve your specific issue, but would couldn't you just do something like this:

```
$('#container-of-the-divs div[id^=title-]').click(function(e) {
    alert('Clicked div with ID: ' + e.target.id);
});
```

You could also just add a class to these elements and select that instead. If you're looking for performance with a ton of items, you could also add the click event onto a parent item, and then do an if statement inside which would create only one event listener, instead of N event listeners. Example:

```
$('#container-of-the-divs').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id.substring(0, 6) == 'title-') {
        alert('Clicked div with ID: ' + e.target.id);
    }
});
```

Or you could just check if $(e.target).hasClass() like mentioned before.

**Updated: Here is a working example based off the code you gave:**

```
<div class="result">
    <div class="resulttext">
        <div id="title-A0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" class="title">
            <a href="#">A0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</a>
        </div>
        <div id="title-B0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" class="title">
            <a href="#">B0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</a>
        </div>
        <div id="title-C0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" class="title">
            <a href="#">C0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</a>
        </div>
        <div id="title-D0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" class="title">
            <a href="#">D0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('div.resulttext div.title').click(function() {
    $i = $(this);
    alert('Clicked div with ID: ' + $i.attr('id'));
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just tried your first snippet. Well, this is a bit strange, it won't detect that happening either...?!

Comment: @Jack Webb-Heller: Yeah there was a typo, I updated both snippets and they both worked for me.

Comment: Ouch! Tried them both after your correction. Still no luck :'(

Comment: OK, I've posted some more examples to my original question.

Comment: This just keeps getting stranger. Works perfectly and as expected with the example. Works perfectly and as expected when encoding in Base36. But, epicly fails when encoding in Base64...?!

Comment: @Jack Webb-Heller: Probably because base64 usually has at least one "=" at the end of the string, which as stated above isn't valid as an ID. base36 is only a-z0-9.

Comment: @Jack Webb-Heller: Why don't you just post the exact output, and remove content that is confidential, but the html structure/id values alone.

Comment: But, there's no "=" output anywhere! An example would look exactly like this - <div id="title-1T" [...] - no equals anywhere. And the allowed characters I've set for Base62 (sorry, I meant Base62, if I said Base64 it's because I'm all coded-out ;) is a-z, A-Z, and 0-9...

Comment: @William, I can't post the exact output as it's generated via Ajax and Right-Click->View Source doesn't show that. Sorry for the amateur reply, but, Firebug won't output <script> tags either, so a Copy-Paste from Firebug seems off the agenda...

Comment: and if you remove the encoding, it works fine? with the CURRENT version?

Comment: OK, sorry! I got the output from Firebug's XHR. I'll append it to my question now :)

Comment: And, @William, yep, removing the capital A-Z encoding (since my IDs aren't high enough for letters yet) it therefore only generates numbers - and that works fine. With the latest jQuery...

Comment: What do you mean by removing the capital A-Z, you're taking the encoded output, and then removing any A-Z characters? Or you're just outputting the ID's (without encoding them)

Comment: OK William, I've added some actual Outputted data to the second edit of my question.

What I mean is, base62's characters are 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ. Base36's characters are 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz - just the same, without capital A-Z included as character options. So, I mean I'm sending the integer ID to be encoded using 0-9 and a-z, not 0-9,a-z AND A-Z. Makes sense?

Comment: @Jack Webb-Heller: You're re-applying the click event on the newly pulled HTML right?

Comment: @Jack Webb-Heller: Also, your document.ready() method will not fire when the AJAX is pulled as the document has already been loaded, since you're pulling it via AJAX just put the JavaScript code under the div element and have it execute right instantly.

Comment: Um, yep... I think so? The jQuery code is sent along with the pulled HTML at the same time, in the same loop, so the values will be the same. I've also tried jQuery's live() thinking that might make a difference, but, nope...

Comment: OK, I'll try your last suggestion now! I was using that previously though with no luck, but, hey, things might be different second time round...

Comment: Nope! Still no luck! This is ridiculous... :S

Comment: @Jack Webb-Heller: Well the method isn't going to be fired with it there, so even if it didn't fully solve the problem, if you did find the problem before, you wouldn't have known because the event was never being fired at all. Make sure your JavaScript is after the HTML.

Comment: FHDUOASE`P1! etc. placed Javascript definitely after the HTML. nothing's happening still. :'(

Comment: sorry for my impatient tone, only, I've been stuck with this problem for 4 hours...

Comment: If I were you, I'd start commenting a large amount of your code out one by one until you find the problem. First, make your "click" event ONLY contain the alert(), comment the rest out. Do an alert BEFORE the click event, to make sure the AJAX is pulling the data and executing the data correctly.

Comment: OK - so, I'm in the UK, and it's nearly midnight here. I need some sleep or I'll go mad. Just briefly, I tried doing what you suggested. I commented out EVERYTHING between <script>, but added an alert("Hello!") to the top. That worked fine. Then, I kept the alert in - at the top, mind you - and uncommented the rest. The alert never fires... But, I don't understand why not, as surely it should fire before processing anything else, so providing it's before the jQuery part it's treated irregardlessly of it?

Comment: Thanks, William, for having the patience of a saint!

Comment: It's most likely because there is an error somewhere, so JavaScript is "dieing". Check your error logs in Firefox. Good night.